# Upgrading from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.0.1 is now giving warnings about the configuration

Tags: hibernate

Just updated from Hibernate 3.6 to Hibernate 4, now getting

```
10-Feb-2012 14:12:31 org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect <init>
WARN: HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
10-Feb-2012 14:12:31 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator c3p0ProviderPresent
WARN: HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
```

I changed

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect");
```

to

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect");
```

and I added

```
config.setProperty("org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator","org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
```

buts its made no difference

I use maven to configure my project, the relvent dependenices are

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
      <version>10.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c3po problem was caused by my maven configuration, hibernated versions of c3po and other packages are now availble in Hibernate 4, so I chnaged maven config to

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Derby Dialect problem is caused by the fact that the org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect class directly subclasses org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect and hence is still subject to the problem, a jira issued has been raised for this.